# After upgrading sencha to 6.6.0 i'm getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'other')

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-cmd

I recently upgraded my app to 6.6.0, after build my app.js and index.html file has some auto-generated code after build. this browserNames and everything is coming from index.html but i don't why its not picking it up. I tried sencha app clean and everything but this issue is not going away. already did sencha app clean but still issue persists.
app.js code.

```
(Ext.env || (Ext.env = {})).Browser = function(userAgent, publish) {
  var me = this, browserPrefixes = Ext.Boot.browserPrefixes, browserNames = Ext.Boot.browserNames, enginePrefixes = me.enginePrefixes, engineNames = me.engineNames, browserMatch = userAgent.match(new RegExp('((?:' + Ext.Object.getValues(browserPrefixes).join(')|(?:') + '))([\\w\\._]+)')), engineMatch = userAgent.match(new RegExp('((?:' + Ext.Object.getValues(enginePrefixes).join(')|(?:') + '))([\\w\\._]+)')), browserName = browserNames.other, engineName = engineNames.other, browserVersion = '', engineVersion = 
  '', majorVer = '', isWebView = false, edgeRE = /(Edge\/)([\w.]+)/, ripple = '', i, prefix, name;
  me.userAgent = userAgent;
  this.is = function(name) {
    return !!this.is[name];
  };
```